# I am trying to make a php/sql page that spits out what amounts to a randomized story

Tags: php, mysql, sql, random

I have an SQL database table that contains 7 columns:

- `firstname`,
- `lastname`,
- `problem`,
- `jobs`,
- `numberofkids`,
- `family`,
- and `hobby`.

Each of these columns gives me parts of a story. I am trying to construct a randomized block of text with their variables; essentially I want to make a story that's different everytime. I tried using the `ORDER BY RAND` function, but it currently only spits out 1 random row, as opposed to randomizing each individual column.

I'm new to php and sql, and I'm sure this is a simple solution, but I've been browsing stackoverflow and forums for a couple of hours with no luck. Here's the current code block:

```
$query = "SELECT firstname, lastname, jobs, family, numberofkids, hobby, problem FROM revgentable ORDER BY RAND () LIMIT 1"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

// Print out result
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "". $row['firstname']. " ". $row['lastname']. " is calling in because ". $row['problem']. ". They work as a ". $row['jobs']. " during the week and have ". $row['numberofkids']. " " . $row['family']. ". They spend their weekends ". $row['hobby']. " as a hobby.";
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Comment: The `ORDER BY` always sorts the rows of the resultset, never the columns. You would have to select a bunch of rows and randomize them in php to do that.

Comment: You should switch into MySQLi or PDO since the old MySQL functions are deprecated and will be removed in the future.

Comment: Appreciate the quick responses (and the helpful edit!). Sounds like I may have bitten off more than I can chew as I don't know how I could perform such a feat in php. To the php books!